# Error when starting Solr after installing collective.solr on Plone 4.1.3 instance

Tags: solr, plone

After installing collective.solr via buildout, I am getting the following error when attempting to run bin/solr-instance start

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bin/solr-instance", line 110, in <module>
 start(True)
File "bin/solr-instance", line 43, in start
 stdout=logfp, stderr=logfp).pid
File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 633, in __init__
 errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/local/Plone/Python-2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1139, in _execute_child
 raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

This is a Plone 4.1.3 zeoserver installation.  Any ideas?

I've tried two different ways of getting this installed.  I first attempted to extend the buildout, as instructed on the pypi instructions.  I also tried inserting the bits directly into my buildout.cfg file.

Here is the buildout.cfg file with the solr bits directly in it.  http://pastie.org/3798794

This is a development build, please excuse the mess....

Comment: "installing collective.solr via buildout" is not very descriptive, I'm afraid. Please consider posting your buildout.cfg file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update on this issue.

It turns out that the issue was server related.  My Red Hat installation did not have java installed.  After installing java on the system with:

yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk*

running bin/solr-instance start resulted in Solr starting as expected.

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that other users can learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this; it works fine for me with the following buildout config:

```
[buildout]
extends = 
    http://build.pythonpackages.com/buildout/plone/4.2.x-dev
    https://raw.github.com/Jarn/collective.solr/master/buildout/solr.cfg
```

E.g.:

```
$ bin/solr-instance start
Solr started with pid 12987
```